# How to capture angular page after login using TestCafe?

Tags: angular, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am able to login to the application using TestCafe code. But after login, it redirects to angular application and I am trying to capture element in that page. But every time I get the below error. *ClientFunction execution was interrupted by page unload. This problem may appear if you trigger page navigation from ClientFunction code*.

I have tried the waitforAngular(); still no luck so far. After clicking on the nextButton it fails for Selector not found

```
import Page from './basic-page-model';
import { waitForAngular } from 'testcafe-angular-selectors';
// import { LoginPage } from './LoginPage';

const page = new Page();
fixture `My first fixture`
    .page `https://test.ci.ai.dynamics.com`
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t
            .typeText(page.nameInput, 'xxxxxx')
            .click(page.nextButton)
    });

test('My first test', async t => {
    await waitForAngular();    
    await t
        const header = await Selector('.d365shell-c-brand-title');
        let headerText = await header.innerText;
        await t
            .expect(headerText).eql('Dynamics 365');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to determine the cause of the issue without detailed research.
Please create a separate bug report in the TestCafe repository using [this form](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and a testing account for the TestCafe team. This will help us find a solution more quickly. If you can not share credentials on a public site, send your report to support@devexpress.com.